# Base interface for a functional interface

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-interface

I recently came across this when trying to provide common functionality to a sub-class of a functional interface. Apparently you cannot do it the way I thought (atleast for Java 8):

```
@FunctionalInterface 
public interface Base<T extends Base<T>> {
    void doit();
        
    default T someDefault() {
        return () -> {}; //incompatible types: T is not a functional interface
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Or was it intentionally disallowed? Maybe an abuse of default methods?

Maybe a use-case example would be a good idea:

```
@FunctionalInterface 
public interface Processor<I, T extends Processor<I, T>> {
    T process(I input);
    default T requireNonNull(I i) {
        return (I input) -> {
            Objects.requireNonNull(i);
            process(input);
        };
    }
}
    
@FunctionalInterface 
public interface Parser<T> extends Processor<String, T> {
    @Override
    default T process(String s) { 
        return parse(s);
    }
    T parse(String s);
}
```

Comment: `T` extends `Base<T>`. The extending `T` is not guaranteed to be a functional interface, it could have added a method, making it not a SAM-type anymore (e.g. `interface TChild extends Base<TChild> { void secondMethod(); }`

Comment: It's not just that it could have added a method, it could be a class and not an interface.  Nothing like this can possibly work.

Comment: It’s a lucky coincidence that in your example, the `process` method has the same parameter types and return type as the `parse` method. Since nothing in the language enforces this, you have demonstrated yourself that even if the sub-interface is a functional interface it may have a different method to implement and there’s no guaranty that the lambda expression in the default method is compatible to the other method.

Answer (score 0):

As said in a comment, it is not guaranteed the interface extending the `Base` interface can be expressed the same way. The only possible is to change the return type to `Base<T>` to make returning the lambda legal, which is guaranteed by the `Base` interface:

```java
default Base<T> someDefault() {
    return () -> {};
}
```

Though it is probably what you don't want. Remember that the ultimate condition you need to satisfy that an interface can be expressed through a lambda expression is that the interface has exactly one abstract (non-default) method, which can be achieved also through extending a different interface.

Here is an example using the `Base` interface that demonstrates why it is not possible to achieve the way you do:

```java
public interface StringBase extends Base<StringBase> {

    void bonk();
}
```

Now `StringBase` cannot be expressed through a lambda expression as long as it provides two abstract methods.

Theoretically, only and only if all interfaces extending the `Base` interface can be compiled with `@FunctionalInterface` would assure that each of them would satisfy such a condition. However, there is no mechanism in Java to enforce this for the sake of successful compilation.

One of the workarounds is to implement the `someDefault` method and provide it as `default` in the extending interface. This assures the instantiated interface has truly a single abstract method and there is no dispute as in the `Base` interface:

```java
public interface Base<T extends Base<T>> {

    void doIt();

    T someDefault();
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface StringBase extends Base<StringBase> {

    @Override
    default StringBase someDefault() {
        return () -> {};
    }
}
```